# How to solve this static field name conflict?

Tags: java, static, static-members

I am writing an Android app and I just created a class.

```
public class ClassA {
    private static int aNumber;
    public static void setANumber (int aNumber) {
        //set the field
    }

    public static int getANumber () {
        return aNumber;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can't set the `aNumber` field because it has the same name as the parameter. If it is an instance field, I can use `this`. But this is a static field! Is there a way to achieve the same as the `this` keyword for static fields? Do I really need to change the parameter name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to it by using the class name:

```
ClassA.aNumber = aNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks! Silly me! I really didn't thought of that!